# How to animate order in layer with keyframe in animation dopesheet in Unity3D?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I can use keyframe animation on Position, Rotation, Scale and even Material, is there anyway i can animate the order in layer for a particular sprite without using code?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing yesterday and havent found an easy way yet. One approach might be to set AnimationEvents and change the order that way. Write an answer here if you find a better way :)

Comment: I have also tried using Z-position instead, by putting those sprites under the same order layer and animate the Z value. In scene view, it looks normal, but in Game view, the renderer ignores the z position and renders the order incorrectly.

Comment: mmh yeah thats the "correct" behaviour for 2d sprites in unity. i think atm you cant go around making it via script.